# What is the source of the prohibition to listen to music in the omer?

Tags: music, sefirat-ha-omer

Where is the earliest source of the prohibition to listen to music in the omer?
I have had a look in [shulchan oruch orach chaim simon תצ״ג](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.493?lang=he), but it does not say there the prohibition to listen to music.

Comment: This answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15660/5346 attributes it to the Magen Avraham (although I skimmed through the Magen Avraham in your link and did not see it). A comment on that answer pointed out that the Shulchan Aruch may have prohibited music all year round anyways, so there would be no additional restriction on music for Sefira that he would mention (outside of music at a wedding).

Comment: Maybe it is just an extension of equating the rules to some level of mourning so even if not explicitly, it would include music.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/2262

Comment: You’re looking in the wrong Siman. Check out תקס:ג.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foundation of the prohibition is in order not to add extra happiness during this time of mourning. The source is from the Magen Avraham that prohibits dancing, and the Aruch Hashulchan learns out that if dancing is prohibited for sure music.

Also learnt from Pri Megadim on Magen Avraham סי' תקנא ס"ק י

[Aruch Hashulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.493.2?lang=he):

> ומותר לעשות סעודה, אך לא בריקודין ומחולות. **וכל שכן שאסור לזמר בכלי
> זמר.** וכן סעודת הרשות מותר, כמו סעודות מריעות, ובלבד בלא ריקודין
> ומחולות.

Comment: Perhaps that Aruch Hashulchan is only talking about music during a meal, which could be more festive. You're extending his words to all music?